# LinqToTwitter PCL 259 Installation Issue

Tags: c#, linq-to-twitter

I am trying to add `LinqToTwitter` to a portable class library project (`Profile 259`), and it is complaining that `the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.  For more information, contact the package author`.

I looked on the website however, and it looks like it supports PCLs?

Any ideas?